# Websocket event receiving old redux state in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, websocket, react-redux

I am building a Chat application using Reactjs and Redux. I have 2 components called **ChatHeads** and **ChatBox** which get mounted side-by-side at the same time.

In the **ChatHeads** component, the selection of User (to whom you want to chat with) is possible and this selection is stored in the redux store as `chatInfo`.

**ChatHeads Component:**

```js
function ChatHeads(props) {
  const {
    dispatch,
    userInfo,
    userId
  } = props;
  const [chatHeads, setChatHeads] = useState([]);

  const handleChatHeadSelect = (chatHead, newChat = false) => {
    dispatch(
      chatActions.selectChat({
        isNewChat: newChat,
        chatId: chatHead.chat._id,
        chatUser: chatHead.user
      })
    );
  };

  const loadChatHeads = async () => {
    const response = await services.getRecentChats(userId, userInfo);
    setChatHeads(response.chats);
  };

  useEffect(() => loadChatHeads(), [userInfo]);

  return (
    //   LOOPING THOUGH ChatHeads AND RENDERING EACH ITEM
    //   ON SELECT OF AN ITEM, handleChatHeadSelect WILL BE CALLED
  );
}

export default connect(
  (state) => {
    return {
      userInfo: state.userInfo,
      userId: (state.userInfo && state.userInfo.user && state.userInfo.user._id) || null,
      selectedChat: (state.chatInfo && state.chatInfo.chat && state.chatInfo.chat._id) || null
    };
  },
  null,
)(ChatHeads);
```

**Chat Actions & Reducers:**

```js
const initialState = {
  isNewChat: false,
  chatId: '',
  chatUser: {},
};

const chatReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  let newState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.CHAT_SELECT:
      newState = { ...action.payload };
      break;

    default:
      newState = state;
      break;
  }
  return newState;
};

export const selectChat = (payload) => ({
  type: actions.CHAT_SELECT,
  payload,
});
```

In the **ChatBox** component, I am establishing a socket connection to the server and based on `chatInfo` object from the global store & ws events, I perform some operations.

**ChatBox Component**:

```js
let socket;

function ChatBox(props) {
  const { chatInfo } = props;

  const onWSMessageEvent = (event) => {
    console.log('onWSMessageEvent => chatInfo', chatInfo);
    // handling event
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket = services.establishSocketConnection(userId);

    socket.addEventListener('message', onWSMessageEvent);

    return () => {
      socket.close();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    //   IF selectedChatId
    //     THEN RENDER CHAT
    //   ELSE
    //     BLANK SCREEN
  );
}

export default connect((state) => {
  return {
    chatInfo: state.chatInfo
  };
}, null)(ChatBox);
```

**Steps**:

1. After both the components are rendered, I am selecting a user in the **ChatHeads** components.
2. Using the Redux DevTools, I was able to observe that the `chatInfo` object has been populated properly.

```js
chatInfo: {
    isNewChat: false,
    chatId: '603326f141ee33ee7cac02f4',
    chatUser: {
        _id: '602a9e589abf272613f36925',
        email: 'user2@mail.com',
        firstName: 'user',
        lastName: '2',
        createdOn: '2021-02-15T16:16:24.100Z',
        updatedOn: '2021-02-15T16:16:24.100Z'
    }
}
```

3. Now, whenever the 'message' event gets triggered in the **ChatBox** component, my expectation is that the `chatInfo` property should have the latest values. But, I am always getting the **initialState** instead of the updated ones.

```js
chatInfo: {
    isNewChat: false,
    chatId: '',
    chatUser: {}
}
```

What am I missing here? Please suggest...

Comment: Hey bro.. please check out `ChatBox Component` you are logging `userInfo` in `onWSMessageEvent`  which is always same maybe.. I think you should get that data from `event`

Comment: I am logging the `chatInfo` in the `onWSMessageEvent` function. I am trying to utilize this (which I receive from the Redux store) whenver there is a ws event. The problem here is I am not getting the updated data.

Comment: Did you try `return {... action.payload }` directly instead of assigning it to `newState` in  `case actions.CHAT_SELECT:` ??

Comment: That did not help! As I've mentioned, using Redux DevTools,  I do see the store getting updated with proper data. But, in the event, I'm still getting the old data...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that when you declare your callback

```js
const { chatInfo } = props;
const onWSMessageEvent = (event) => {
  console.log('onWSMessageEvent => chatInfo', chatInfo);
  // handling event
};
```

it remembers what `chatInfo` is right at this moment of declaration (which is the initial render). It doesn't matter to the callback that the value is updated inside the store and inside the component render scope, what matters is the callback scope and what `chatInfo` is referring to when you declare the callback.

If you want to create a callback that can always read the latest state/props, you can instead keep the `chatInfo` inside a mutable reference.

```js
const { chatInfo } = props;
// 1. create the ref, set the initial value
const chatInfoRef = useRef(chatInfo);
// 2. update the current ref value when your prop is updated
useEffect(() => chatInfoRef.current = chatInfo, [chatInfo]);
// 3. define your callback that can now access the current prop value
const onWSMessageEvent = (event) => {
  console.log('onWSMessageEvent => chatInfo', chatInfoRef.current);
};
```

You can check [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-spence-d3m1y?file=/src/App.js) to see the difference between using ref and using the prop directly.

You can consult the [docs about stale props](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function) and [useRef docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

---

Broadly speaking, the issue is that you're trying to manage a global subscription (socket connection) inside a much more narrow-scope component.

Another solution without `useRef` would look like

```js
useEffect(() => {
    socket = services.establishSocketConnection(userId);

    socket.addEventListener('message', (message) => handleMessage(message, chatInfo));

    return () => {
      socket.close();
    };
  }, [chatInfo]);
```

In this case the message event handler is passed the necessary information through arguments, and the `useEffect` hook re-runs every time we get a new `chatInfo`.

However, this probably doesn't align with your goals unless you want to open a separate socket for each chat and close the socket every time you switch to a different chat.

Thus, the "proper" solution would entail moving the socket interaction up in your project. One hint is that you are using `userId` to open the socket, which means that it's supposed to run once you know your `userId`, not once the user selects a chat.

To move the interaction up, you could store incoming messages in a redux store and pass the messages to the `ChatBox` component through props. Or you could create connect to the socket in `ChatHeads` component and pass the messages down to the `ChatBox`. Something like

```js
function ChatHeads(props) {
  const {
    dispatch,
    userInfo,
    userId
  } = props;
  const [chatHeads, setChatHeads] = useState([]);

  const loadChatHeads = async () => {
    const response = await services.getRecentChats(userId, userInfo);
    setChatHeads(response.chats);
  };

  useEffect(() => loadChatHeads(), [userInfo]);

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    socket = services.establishSocketConnection(userId);
    socket.addEventListener('message', (msg) => setMessages(messages.concat(msg)));
  }, [userId]);
    return () => socket.close();
}

   return (
   // render your current chat and pass the messages as props
   )
```

Or you could create a reducer and dispatch a `chatActions.newMessage` event and then the messages get to the current chat using redux.

The main point is that if you need `chatInfo` to open the socket, then every time `chatInfo` changes, you might have to open a new socket, so it makes sense to add the dependency to the `useEffect` hook. If it only depends on `userId`, then move it up to where you get the `userId` and connect to the socket there.

Comment: This solved the issue. But, If I have serveal such variables that I want to use in the callback, should I be creating refs for all of them in a similar way. Is there any elegant way to tackle this?

Comment: @SreekarMouli I've added some tips I think could help you.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Another quick doubt.

In the parent component, I have created a `socket` variable using the `useRef`. I am passing this `socket` to the child component where I want to listen to some events. But, `socket.current` is null. How can I get the child component to re-render after the `socket.current` has the ws connection. I can't use `socket.current` in the `useEffect` of the child component as mutable objects can't be used as a dependency, I guess?

Comment: This isn't an exact science, so hard to tell, but I would double check why it's necessary to let child component handle the socket. I would typically try to do socket interactions in one place, then create some glue between the socket and the application.
Your app appears to be about chatting, so the components should probably be passed chats, messages, users, etc.

Comment: In other words, when your socket gets a message, use it to update your application state. The components then use this state to render UI and handle interactions. They don't care about whether the state changes because of socket messages, `setTimeout` triggers, API calls, or user actions.

Comment: In my application, **ChatHeads** component and **ChatBox** component are the child components. There are some events which are specific to the **ChatHeads** components (like user_selected, where I want to emit events based on certain element clicks which are specific to the component / to update couple of state variables which are specific to the component and not part of the global redux store ). So, I wanted to use the socket in the child component. I can definitely move those state variabels to the parent or to the global store. But, I feel like the current placements make sense.

Comment: I will move that to a separate question

Answer (score 0):

using `store.getState()` to get the latest states

I had the same issue where I had latest value in redux store
but getting previous/stale value inside socket

above answer with refs did not worked for me

So I use `store.getState()` to get the current/latest states;

```
 socket.on("message", async (data: any) => {
         const state = store.getState();   // using this
       console.log(state.chatInfo)   // I get latest value here
}
```