# Redux state keeps changing back and forth without dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building a Chat application using Reactjs and Redux. I have a **ChatHeads** component where I am rendering a list of Users. If one of them is clicked, then I am dispatching an action to store that info in redux under `chatInfo` key.

**Component**:

```js
function ChatHeads(props) {
    const dispatch = props.dispatch;
    const { userId, userInfo, selectedChatId, state } = props;
    const [chatHeads, setChatHeads] = useState([]);

    // setInterval(() => console.log('ChatHeads => state.userInfo', JSON.stringify(state.userInfo)), 5000);
    // setInterval(() => console.log('ChatHeads => state.app', JSON.stringify(state.app)), 5000);
    setInterval(() => console.log('ChatHeads => state.chatInfo', JSON.stringify(state.chatInfo)), 5000);

    const handleChatHeadSelect = (chatHead, isNewChat = false) => {
        dispatch(
            chatActions.selectChat({
                isNewChat,
                chatId: chatHead.chat._id,
                chatUser: chatHead.user,
            })
        );
    };

    const loadChatHeads = async () => {
        const response = await services.getRecentChats(userId, userInfo);
        setChatHeads(response.chats);
    };

    useEffect(() => loadChatHeads(), [userInfo]);

    const renderChatHead = (chatHead, index) => {
        const fullName = `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`;
        return (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
                <ListItem
                    button
                    onClick={() => handleChatHeadSelect(chatHead)}
                    selected={selectedChatId === chat._id}
                >
                    <ListItemText primary={fullName} />
                </ListItem>
                <Divider />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    };

    return (
        <Paper id="chat-heads" className={classes.chatHeads} elevation={3}>
            {/* {...some components} */}
            <List>{chatHeads && chatHeads.map(renderChatHead)}</List>
        </Paper>
    );
}

export default connect(
    (state) => {
        return {
            userId: (state.userInfo && state.userInfo.user && state.userInfo.user._id) || null,
            userInfo: state.userInfo,
            selectedChatId: (state.chatInfo && state.chatInfo.chatId) || null,
            state: state,
        };
    },
    null
)(ChatHeads);
```

**Action and Reducer**:

```js
import actions from '../actionTypes';

export const selectChat = (payload) => ({
  type: actions.CHAT_SELECT,
  payload,
});

const initialState = {
  isNewChat: false,
  chatId: '',
  chatUser: {},
};

const chatReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  let newState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.CHAT_SELECT:
      newState = { ...action.payload };
      break;

    default:
      newState = state;
      break;
  }
  return newState;
};

export default chatReducer;
```

I have added a `setInterval` to the **ChatHeads** component to log the `chatInfo` from the gloal state. If no user is selected from the List, the `chatInfo` is similar to the `initialState` object which is fine. But, after I select an user, **the `selectChat` action is dispatched which changes the `chatInfo`** (which I can observe from the Redux DevTools).

After this, whenver the logs are triggered, I see 6 logs and in 4 of them, the `chatInfo` seems to be equal to `initialState`. The other 2 logs have the expected log. There are no additional dispatches that are happening but the state keeps changing back and forth. This **ChatHeads** component is only used once in the app.

Expected log

```js
chatInfo: {
    isNewChat: false,
    chatId: '603326f141ee33ee7cac02f4',
    chatUser: {
        _id: '602a9e589abf272613f36925',
        email: 'user2@mail.com',
        firstName: 'user',
        lastName: '2',
        createdOn: '2021-02-15T16:16:24.100Z',
        updatedOn: '2021-02-15T16:16:24.100Z'
    }
}
```

Please explain this behavior...

Comment: The setInterval is logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) and you never clear the interval so every time the component renders you add another interval.

Comment: That is a good article. I have followed that and now, I am getting the expected result. Similarly, I am binding a websocket event to a function without proper closure. Will I see the same behaviour (please check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/66310269/8208804).